# iTextSharp, how can I use my own font in pdf document

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

When I run the code below in localhost it's OK, the pdf file is being created with my font but it does not work on the server.

I put my own font in the fonts folder and uploaded to the server correctly.

The part of my code:

```
string fontpath = Server.MapPath("~/fonts/");

Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(fontpath + "TTKBDikTemelAbece.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 14, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK );

sb.Append("<font face='"+font.Familyname+"'>");
sb.Append("<table width='100%' align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='8'>");
```

Comment: Hello Zafer, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) are some more resources to help you. As an aside your question lacks a lot of detail please expand.

Comment: Have you installed your custom fonts on server as well?

Comment: the font is in the "fonts" folder inside root folder..